# how could they see the fire signals so far away?

Tags: geography, rosh-chodesh-new-month, fire-burning, maseches-rosh-hashana, babylonian-exile

(Please include header and footer when redistributing this material.)

---

```
             THE DAFYOMI DISCUSSION LIST

  brought to you by Kollel Iyun Hadaf of Yerushalayim
         Rosh Kollel: Rabbi Mordecai Kornfeld
                  daf@dafyomi.co.il
```

[REPLY TO THIS MESSAGE TO DISCUSS THE DAF WITH THE KOLLEL]

---

Rosh Hashanah 023: Distance of Pumbedisa to the Border of Eretz Yisrael

binyomin zev asks:

Thank you for this service. from the gemoro it sounds that from the last fire in Eretz Yisroel, Pumbedisa got to know that they had been mekadesh the chodesh on the 30th day. But Pumbedisa is Fallujah of today & that is at least 600miles from the border of EY (even if we are including Ever Hayarden like the Tosfos Rosh). How could they see it from so far? Thank you

binyomin zev, Manchester-United Kingdom

Comment: Should you really be posting this person's email address here?

Comment: Also it seems you are using their forum to post your answer here? With respect it's a bit odd that you post the question and then answer it as if you're speaking to the OP?

Comment: thank you @Harel13, i removed it now

Comment: @Dov you are making a good point. I really was asked to answer the question, and yet I want to hear if someone hear has any other insights to add and make the answer better. How do you think I should go about it?

Comment: @yishairasowsky - what I would do, is perhaps in the question link to their forum and say I came across this question and was interested in it. Then build on the question a bit to make it into your own and then ask does anyone have any suggested answers requesting sources to make the answers based on mefarshim rather than glorified comments.

Answer (score -2):

One might understand that there were additional fire station(s) in between, from which Pumbedisa saw the signal, and to whom Pumbedisa appears as a great big fire.

(I was asked to answer the question, and yet I want to hear if someone hear has any other insights to add and make the answer better. )

Comment: R’ Yochanan on 23B clearly says there were only 8 parsa between mountains. The Gemara explains that the distance changed after the churban. Tosfos says that Biram is from EY but there was a strip that extended all the way to Bavel that had mountains on them. The Yaavetz says that Biram is from CHUL and all the other mountains as well. So there are many ways to understand that the distance wasn’t that far